# Added external static library in IntelliJ Java project that Gradle doesn't see

Tags: java, opencv, intellij-idea, gradle, static-libraries

I want to build a static library as a jar, so that it can be included into my project (without the need to compile it within our project).

I built a static library (with java and ant references valid):

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
build -j8
```

In IntelliJ, I referenced the .jar file as a dependency:
ProjectStructure > Modules > Dependencies > Add Jar (scope = compile)

The file shows up in External Libraries as expected.  Code completion works, e.g.  `import org.opencv.core.Core;` is found.

I noticed that unlike other External Libraries, this one doesn't have a "Gradle:" prefix.

When I build, I get an error:

```
/Users/tj/Documents/projects/myProject/src/main/java/edu/wpi/cscore/CameraServerJNI.java:17: 
error: package org.opencv does not exist
import org.opencv.core;
```

Did I miss a step?
[image: External Libraries]

build.gradle:
[image]

Comment: Why should it have a gradle prefix? Did you add it in gradle build file?

Comment: The build.gradle file was provided, and I don't see how the 3 External Libraries are referenced from within the file.  I added a new External Library (opencv) and didn't expect to have to add it to build.gradle since the others seem to be working.  See screenshot added above.

Answer (score 1):

Doing so as you did (ProjectStructure > Modules > Dependencies > Add Jar) is not proper way of adding libraries into the Gradle or Maven project. All project's libraries in this case should be specified in build file, and Intellij Idea will automatically discover them and will include into its own Project description.

Comment: The gradle.build file was provided (see above screenshot).  The External Libraries with the gradle: prefix don't seem to be referenced in this file.  For that reason, I didn't expect a need to edit this file to include my External Library.

Comment: There is also such thing in IDEA as auto-importing of gradle/maven libraries. Did you turn it on?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that feature, and that might explain why it didn't "auto-import" the newly added library.  I'll look into this thx